# MIDI - MidiMessage Program Change with Instrument From Different Bank

Tags: java, midi, midi-instrument

The soundbank of the default synthesizer I'm using contains a variety of different instruments. For example, this code snippet...

```java
Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
synthesizer.open();
Instrument instruments = synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank().getInstruments();
for (Instrument i : instruments)
    System.out.println(i);
```

... prints the following:

```
Instrument: Piano 1      bank #0 preset #0
Instrument: Piano 2      bank #0 preset #1
[...]
Instrument: Applause     bank #0 preset #126
Instrument: Gun Shot     bank #0 preset #127
Instrument: SynthBass101 bank #128 preset #38
Instrument: Trombone 2   bank #128 preset #57
[...]
Instrument: Machine Gun  bank #128 preset #127
Instrument: Echo Pan     bank #256 preset #102
Instrument: String Slap  bank #256 preset #120
[...]
Instrument: Lasergun     bank #256 preset #127
[...]
Instrument: Starship     bank #1024 preset #125
Instrument: Carillon     bank #1152 preset #14
[...]
Instrument: Choir Aahs 2 bank #4096 preset #52
```

I can play an instrument from any of these banks through `MidiChannel`, the  `programChange` method, and `noteOn`, like so (this plays instrument 14 from bank 1152, "Carillon"):

```
MidiChannel channel = synthesizer.getChannels()[0];
if (channel != null) {
    channel.programChange(1152, 14);
    channel.noteOn(70, 100);
}
```

I want to add a program change event to a sequence's track so I can play the "Carillon" instrument in the sequence. I tried doing this with a `ShortMessage`:

```
Sequence sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 2);
Track track = sequence.createTrack();
ShortMessage pcMessage = new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.PROGRAM_CHANGE, 0, 14, 0);
track.add(new MidiEvent(pcMessage, 0));
```

But this changes the instrument to instrument 14 in bank 0 ("Tubular-bell") when I'm instead looking for instrument 14 in bank 1152. Attempting to change either of the last two arguments in the ShortMessage constructor to 1152 resulted in a `javax.sound.midi.InvalidMidiDataException` for the data byte value being out of range. The other MidiMessage subclasses don't seem to contain an option to load instruments from other banks, either.

How can I use an instrument from a different bank in the MidiEvent's MidiMessage?

Comment: May depends on when and how you send the MIDI Bank Select message. The snippets does not show any bank selection operations. If you just forget it, then try this first. If you did it, I may have an answer, telling more about possible issues with MIDI Bank Select.

Comment: @Hibou57 As far as I know bank select commands are used for MidiChannels (which I had in the form of `channel.programChange(1152, 14)` unless I am mistaken). Is there an equivalent for MidiMessage?

Comment: Okay… I don't know the Java MIDI API, so I did not noticed. The bank number is surprisingly big (it's uncommon to me). The issue may be that with Bank Select message (which must be implicit here), there are three possible forms: GM2 or GS or XG. But if the API does not allow to deal with Bank Select message directly, it will not help to know about it.

Comment: Also, the `ShortMessage(ShortMessage.PROGRAM_CHANGE, 0, 14, 0)` look dubious to me. Have you checked this? There should be two arguments (channel and program number), but there are three here. Have you tried to turn one of the zero into something else? Looks like one of the argument may be a bank number with this API.

Comment: @Hibou57 The four-parameter form of the `ShortMessage` constructor creates the MIDI status byte from separate command and channel values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the MIDI protocol itself, bank numbers are split into two 7-bit parts and transmitted as the value of two [controllers](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php), "Bank Select" and "Bank Select LSB":

```
... = new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.CONTROL_CHANGE, 0, 0,  1152 >> 7);   // = 9
... = new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.CONTROL_CHANGE, 0, 32, 1152 & 0x7f); // = 0
... = new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.PROGRAM_CHANGE, 0, 14, 0);
```

Please note that different standards (GS, XG, GM2) name the two parts of the bank select number differently.
In this case, the Carillon is from the GS standard, which defines it as "variation number 9", which is the MSB controller. But the controller name does not matter; you get the correct instrument as long as you set controller 0 to 9.